# How to uninstall Windows Mail?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, uninstall, windows-mail

How do I uninstall "Windows Mail" (not Windows Live Mail).

When I want to use IMAP (or POP), I normally use Windows Live Mail. I have no need for Windows Mail. (Windows Mail, in its old incarnation, used to be called "Outlook Express").

I have looked under Control Panel. I have done Google Search. Have come up with nothing so far.

Hence my question...

**Update:**

I had already looked under Control Panel → Programs and Features →  Add/Remove Windows Components →  and Windows Mail does not appear here.

Comment: "Windows Mail, in its old incarnation, used to be called "Outlook Express" So is WLM, but is more flexible.

Answer (score 13):

Windows Mail is a Windows system component and cannot be uninstalled or removed,
so Microsoft has not supplied any means for that.

To **remove**, try renaming WinMail.exe to something else, found in `C:\Program Files\Windows Mail`.
You might first use [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to see if it's set to start automatically with the computer.

If all you want is to **disable** WinMail, see details in the article :
[How to Enable or Disable Windows Mail in Vista](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/165150-windows-mail-enable-disable.html).

The procedure is to open the Local Group Policy Editor -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Mail, right-click on "Turn off Windows Mail application" and click on Properties, then select "(dot) Disabled or Not Configured" and click OK.

[image]

Comment: you should select "Enable", not "DisableNot-configured" in GPEdit. It's a double negative - "turn off" should be "enabled" to be really "off". `If you *enable* this setting, access to the Windows Mail application is *denied*.` - quote from the help there

Comment: from Microsoft help quote session it said ` "If you enable this setting, access to the Windows Mail application is denied.
If you disable or do not configure this setting, access to the Windows Mail application is allowed." `

Answer (score 9):

The OP's question was how to remove WinMail from a computer. The other suggestions will disable or only rename the file. If you want WinMail permanently gone from your system, this simple BAT file will do it:

```
:: Take ownership of the folders
TakeOwn /F "C:\Program Files\Windows Mail" /R /D Y
TakeOwn /F "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Mail" /R /D Y

:: Grant full control to Administrators, the user running this, and SYSTEM
ICACLS "C:\Program Files\Windows Mail" /T /Grant:R "Administrators":(OI)(CI)F
ICACLS "C:\Program Files\Windows Mail" /T /Grant:R %UserDomain%\%UserName%:(OI)(CI)F
ICACLS "C:\Program Files\Windows Mail" /T /Grant:R "SYSTEM":(OI)(CI)F
ICACLS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Mail" /T /Grant:R "Administrators":(OI)(CI)F
ICACLS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Mail" /T /Grant:R %UserDomain%\%UserName%:(OI)(CI)F
ICACLS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Mail" /T /Grant:R "SYSTEM":(OI)(CI)F

:: Unhide WinMail.exe
Attrib -S -H "C:\Program Files\Windows Mail\WinMail.exe"
Attrib -S -H "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Mail\WinMail.exe"

:: Delete the WinMail folders
RD /S /Q "C:\Program Files\Windows Mail"
RD /S /Q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Mail"
```

Comment: this is the best way I've found to remove windows accessories that cannot be uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

See If there is an entry in Control Panel> Programs and Features>Add Remove Windows Components, if not, then you can attempt to delete the program folder.

Comment: As I mentioned in my original query "I have looked under Control Panel...". Windows Mail does not appear under "Windows Components". It cannot be uninstalled from there.

Comment: You were not specific as to where in control panel you looked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article on how to install Windows Mail on Windows 7, one could reverse engineer the instructions to remove it from your system.

http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=322047

Answer (score 0):

After removing Winmail.exe , try creating a directory named "Winmail.exe" in its old location.  That way, maybe the OS cannot put the file back because there is a directory there with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled my Windows Mail, but I had to alter ownership and permissions to allow it. You will find the options for this within the "properties" of the Mail folder itself.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain how to accomplish this?  There isn't enough information here to really be useful if the reader doesn't already know the answer.